# lookin for ftp proxy

Tags: security, ftp

Does somebody know about ftp proxy server ?
the idea is to put "transparent" ftp server that will sit between the client and the real server and will run some checks in order to decide whatever the user/ip data should be passed the real server. 
I've fount some packages such as 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/dapper/proxy-suite
and 
http ://www. ftpproxy.org/
but those are old packages that don't seem to be maintained any more.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify by avoiding the old dual-port FTP protocols (FTP and FTPS).  What I mean by that is that if you use SFTP , since it uses a single pipeline (unlike typical FTP), then you could use ANY proxy server to do the job  except that you cant really sniff the traffic because its encrypted.

For my answer, i'd say to look at this:
http://frox.sourceforge.net/

Comment: actually, SFTP is sorta like a proxy.   if you were to open a few SSH tunnels to a machine on port 20 and 21  and then ftp through the proxy tunnels, you would get something similar to SFTP probably.

Answer (score 0):

I've never use it this way, but I know OpenBSD has an embed ftp proxy.
You should have a look at [the documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ftp-proxy) it could give you an idea.

Comment: this is the ftpproxy.org package

Comment: I wouldn't want to use OpenBSD for anything anyways, because it is modeled from the concept of "security through obsolescence".

Answer (score 0):

Watchguard firewalls can do this. Filter by content, scan for viruses, pattern match file names, etc, etc.

Comment: yeah, but I bet MonoWall, IpCop, or SmoothWall can also do it and they are free...

Comment: Then that would probably be better then. We only use Watchguard at work, so that is all I was 100% sure about.

Comment: The "proxy" needs to serve windows servers , so sftp isn't an option.